# StackOverflowError when showing ProgressDialog

Tags: android, dialog, progressdialog

I'm showing `ProgressDialog` as follows:

```
private void showProgressDialog() {
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.logging_in));
    mProgressDialog.show();
}
```

But on some devices (Sony Xperia L ; 4.1.2) I get this exception:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:236)
    at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:336)
    at android.app.ProgressDialog.onCreate(ProgressDialog.java:198)
    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:351)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:256)
    at com.x.x.activity.LoginActivity.showProgressDialog(LoginActivity.java:140)
    at com.x.x.activity.LoginActivity.onPasswordBtnClick(LoginActivity.java:119)
    at com.x.x.activity.LoginActivity$$ViewInjector$3.onClick(LoginActivity$$ViewInjector.java:40)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4129)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17143)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4802)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:813)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:580)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT:** I'm using ButterKnife and this method is in `Activity` class.

```
@OnClick(R.id.login_btn_password)
void onPasswordBtnClick(TextView textview) {
    if (mLoginName.getEditableText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        MyToast.showToast(R.string.empty_username, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        return;
    }

    showProgressDialog();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show here complete code?
From where you are invoking this method?

Comment: try new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have "solved" problem. I don't see connection between this two things, but adding google mail to Google Play (and probably updating Google Services) solved the problem.